# Label and display chart

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I want to display a column chart with proper labels and the columns placed in the correct spot.

I have a worksheet for each month of the year.  Row 2 is the days of the month i.e. numbered 1 to 31, (going from column 'B' to column 'AF').  Column 'A' has different products, from row 3 to row 12 (numbered 1 to 10). Throughout the month, production numbers are placed into a day and for a product.  For example, product #4 on the 5th of the month would have a production number placed in range("F6"). Product #1 on the 31st would go into range("AF3").

I have the following code that produces a column chart on Userform1.  It works well.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim chartData As Range
Dim oChrt As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set oChrt = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Oct").ChartObjects.Add _
            (Left:=24, Width:=768, Top:=66, Height:=402)
With oChrt.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.sheets("Oct").Range("B6:AF6")
    .ChartType = xl3DColumn
End With

Dim imageName As String
imageName = Application.DefaultFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "tempChart.gif"

oChrt.Chart.Export FileName:=imageName

ThisWorkbook.sheets("Oct").ChartObjects.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(imageName)

End Sub
```

The problem is the x-axis.  The x-axis is labelled 1 to whatever it needs i.e. if there is data in columns 'E'(6), 'J'(10) and 'T'(20) (for a particular row) the chart will only show about 15 columns and put 'E' in the 1st column, 'J' in the 5th column and 'T' in the 15th.

What I want is for the chart to leave columns 1 to 5 blank and show 'E' in 6 as it is in the worksheet. If that's all I can accomplish that would be fine.

If, however, it is possible to create another row of labels along the x-axis, I would love to have the day of the month below the number of the month. The days (as text) are in row 1 of the worksheet and the numbers are in row 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your `With`-Block:

```
With oChrt.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.sheets("Oct").Range("B6:AF6")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B2","AF2")
    .ChartType = xl3DColumn
End With
```

Comment: Sorry, that line had no effect at all - nothing changed.

Comment: I did a work-around for my problem.  If there was no value in 'B6' i.e. the first day of the month, I placed a nominal value (0.00001).  This forced the chart to start from column B.  I also placed 31 tiny 'label boxes' below the chart (i.e. image) right on the userform where each one lines up below the day number of the month.  I will place an appropriate letter (M for Monday, T for Tuesday, etc) in each box based on the day of the month.  Kind of sloppy but I think it will work out ok.

Comment: I had a look on numerous websites and there doesn't seem to be (or I haven't found it jet) a satisfying answer (in my eyes).